# Why i am getting the error like must me nonnegative?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got Must be non negative,index was out of range  error though there is data in all cells and the index is not overflowed too

```
private void editToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmProfileMaster frm = new frmProfileMaster();
            frm.status = "Edit";
            frm.pid = Convert.ToInt32(gdvProfile.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
            frm.Show();
        }
```

Comment: Try `String myValue = gdvProfile.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString() ` at the start of your code , and check `myValue` .

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is no data available, or no row present at 0th index.

Hence, when you are pointing to `SelectedRows[0].Cells[0]` , since it is having no row, it gives you the error.

In quickwatch see the values you are getting and accordingly make the code.

Comment: Hey zey I checked as String myValue = gdvProfile.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString() but i got same error. MNS , the data is available but still ...

Comment: in quickwatch just see gdvProfile.SelectedRows[1].Cells[1].Value you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Here you want is your gridviews first cell controls value. Right.
    You can try like,

```
 //if your first cell control is label then
 Label lbl = (Label)gdvProfile.Rows[0].FindControl("lbl");
 frm.pid = Convert.ToInt32(lbl.Text);

 Same way you can check for all control.

Hope it helps.
```

Comment: Thanx harshil but i want the solution of my exact problem . i need to debug that because it is working on some other form of my project rather than using oither method

Comment: I am not familiar with SelectedRows property of gridview. I can imagine that at the time of your event, your gridview may not have any selected row. That's why it is showing you this error. I may be wrong. You can try like, **GridViewRow row = gdvProfile.SelectedRow;** if row is null, then your gridview is not having any selected row.

Comment: Thanx to all but i detect that why i was getting it. in gridview at the run time in first there is a column in whiuch there is arrow hover pointing to the row . How can i disable through gridview property?

Comment: Thanx all i got solutions.